# Accessing the nth index of array in o(1)

Tags: java, python, arrays

A very basic question, How we can access the nth index directly in O(1) cost? When we initialize an array, Is there some data structure built for keeping the addresses of each index (For accessing later in o(1) cost)? Otherwise it has to traverse from the beginning to the nth index in array. What is the reason for accessing the array elements it in o(1) ?

Comment: uhh, an array IS the structure that accesses in O(1). you are thinking of a linked list

Comment: Generally this is done by storing the array in contiguous memory. So if the address of the start of the array is known, the machine can find the address of any further position by adding the appropriate amount to the start address. That's why array access is O(1) and (for instance) linked list access is not.

Comment: @khelwood `So if the address of the start of the array is known` How we know the start address of array? We just give `A[4]` for accessing the 4th element.

Comment: `A` is a reference to the starting memory position

Comment: You might find the table "Comparison of list data structures" table in this Wikipedia article helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_vs._dynamic_arrays (Your question concerns the row of the table labeled "Indexing".)

Comment: @Adirio Finding the first index of array, is it the work of Programming language of Operating system?

Comment: That's a completely new question, that I can't answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing an array in O(1) is possible because the calculation to access the data you want is done in one step.

How this is done is quite simple, say you create an array of 10 integers.

```
int[] intArray = new int[10];
```

What is happening here is that you are asking for a block of memory that is big enough to contain 10 integers (In Java they are 32 bit, so 10 * 4 Bytes long).

When the memory has been reserved, the memory address at the beginning of this block is given back and put into the intArray variable (a variable containing an address/reference to something else is called a pointer).

To make this easier to understand you can picture memory (RAM) as a long list of single byte blocks that each have an address.

```
Data:    [ 00000000 ] [ 11111111 ] [ 00001111 ]
Address:      7             8            9
```

When you use an index to get access to a part of the array, what is happening is that the index is used to calcuate the memory address of the block you want on the fly.

e.g. using the example above

```
char[] charArray = new char[3]; // This returns memory address 7

charArray[1] = 'b'; // Here the memory address is calcuated with the formula
                 // startAddress + index * Size Per Element
```

In this case startAddress is the value in charArray, index is the number 1 and size per element is the size of an individual char (1 Byte) so it gives us the memory address of 8.

Comment: `When the memory has been reserved, the memory address at the beginning of this block is given back and put into the intArray variable (a variable containing an address/reference to something else is called a pointer).` Need reference of this.

Answer (score -1):

As said by @Nullman in the comments, and at least when refering to Python, `list`s are accessed in O(1).

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity